# Finding weekly returns from daily returns company-wise

Tags: r, date, dataframe, dplyr, xts

I have data which look something like this

```
co_code company_name co_stkdate dailylogreturn
1        A           01-01-2000  0.76
1        A           02-01-2000  0.75
.
.
.
1        A           31-12-2019  0.54
2        B           01-01-2000  0.98
2        B           02-01-2000  0.45
```

.
.
And so on

I want to find **weekly returns** which is equal to sum of daily log return for one week.

output should look something like this

```
 co_code company_name co_stkdate weeklyreturns
    1        A           07-01-2000  1.34
    1        A           14-01-2000  0.95
    .
    .
    .
    1        A           31-12-2019  0.54
    2        B           07-01-2000  0.98
    2        B           14-01-2000  0.45
```

I tried to apply functions in quantmod package but those functions are applicable to only xts objects. Another issue in xts objects is that function "group_by()" can't be used. Thus, I want to work in usual dataframe only.

Code look something like this

```
library(dplyr)
### Reading txt file
df <- read.csv("33339_1_120_20190405_165913_dat.csv")
```

#### Calculating daily log returns

```
df <- mutate(df, "dailylogrtn"=log(nse_returns)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

#### Formatting date

```
df$co_stkdate<- as.Date(as.character(df$co_stkdate), format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: What I understand from my trading knowledge that there are holidays and closing days (saturdays and sundays) at almost all exchanges. you need to create a dataset that should have these days included but trading returns on these days to be 0s to make a full 52 (or 53) weeks in a year (depending upon leap and non leap years). This is a typical exercise. But if you want to continue from your actual data, use ceiling() for grouping data by 7 days.

Comment: something like `DF %>%
   group_by(group = ceiling((1:nrow(DF)/ 7)))` and then compute the means for each group.

Comment: How to do that "typical exercise" ? Any ideas...Of adding days

Comment: sure. one way is fill these days and since these were holidays, we usually take the last trading day's closing prices on these days opening as well as closing prices too. This is done to avoid any dates, overshooting than actual 52 or 53 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't know how many days of every week you got a `dailylogreturn`, there might be NAs, I recommend grouping by week and year:

```
#sample data
df <-   data.frame(co_stkdate = rep(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2000-01-07"), to = as.Date("2000-02-07"), by = 1), 2),
                   dailylogreturn = abs(round(rnorm(64, 1, 1), 2)),
                   company_name = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 32))


df %>%
  mutate(co_stkdate = as.POSIXct(co_stkdate),
         year = strftime(co_stkdate, "%W"),
         week = strftime(co_stkdate, "%Y")) %>%
  group_by(company_name, year, week) %>%
  summarise(weeklyreturns = sum(dailylogreturn, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   company_name, year [12]
   company_name year  week  weeklyreturns
   <fct>        <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
 1 A            01    2000           6.31
 2 A            02    2000           6.11
 3 A            03    2000           6.02
 4 A            04    2000           8.27
 5 A            05    2000           4.92
 6 A            06    2000           0.5 
 7 B            01    2000           1.82
 8 B            02    2000           6.6 
 9 B            03    2000           7.55
10 B            04    2000           7.63
11 B            05    2000           7.54
12 B            06    2000           1.03
```

Comment: thanks. This worked for me. But, I am getting output like 00_2000 00_2001 00_2002  00_2003...then its 01_2000 01_2001. How do I arrange that column ?

Comment: Hm, if you care for the order you could split the `yearweek` column up into one for `week`and one for `year`, group by both columns (+ company_name) and arrange afterwards by `week`and `year` if necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have sample data, I assume this should work:

```
df %>%
   group_by(group = ceiling((1:nrow(df)/ 7))) %>%
   summarise(mean = mean(weeklyreturns))
```